# Read the first line of a file using bash

Tags: bash

Does anyone know of a simple one liner to read the first line of a file in bash?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
read -r FIRSTLINE < filename
```

Same result as the other answers but faster because it doesn't spawn any process, as "read" is a built-in bash command.

Comment: good point, +1 for you

Comment: This performs much better than doing 'head -n 1'. I was reading the first line of 265 files and my time went from approximately 15 seconds to less than 1 second

Answer (score 16):

```
head -1
```

simply

Comment: care to explain? :)

Comment: There few to explain .. simply does what the questions asks :) Retain 1 line at the beginning of a file

Answer (score 6):

```
FIRSTLINE=`head -n 1 filename`
```

Stores the line in a variable for later use (note the inverted apostrophes).

Comment: _$(command)_ is an alternate form that avoid the use of back ticks, not even simple to be found on certain keyboards.

Comment: good answer, but I'm voting down because e-t172's answer is better.  Read is intended for this, and it's built-in to bash, as he says.

Comment: nah, voting down a "good answer" becouse it is not the best possible is not so polite don't you think?

Comment: Lee - Why not just upvote the one you like instead? Downvotes should only be given for factually incorrect information or off topic stuff.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR == 1' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: this will scan full file, then return the first line, which is inefficient for large file. read -r is better.

Comment: `awk '{ print; exit; }'` will return the first line without reading the whole file, so if you cannot use `read -r` (e.g. because you are not reading into a variable) and don't want to use head for some reason (e.g. it sometimes fails with exit code 141, as it does for me) then that's the `awk` equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

`head -n 1` should do the trick